# after replacing /var/www/html directory, apache does not work anymore

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I'm setting up an aws ec2 instance. After installing apache, it has /var/www/html. Then I replaced the html with my own html directory which contains my php files. Now index.php file is not accessible from browser anymore. I searched online, and could not find any solution. I would really appreciate if anyone can help.

I can access test.php or test.html. But can not access index.php which actually should be loaded by default without giving the name.

The directory I copied over is wordpress, if this information is useful. And right now, the browser just shows a blank page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the permissions on the file(s)

```
ls -lR /var/www
```

It may be that the Apache user (e.g. www-data) does not have permissions to them.

```
chmod 744 -R /var/www/html
```

And try restarting Apache too.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried, it gave me this now: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Can you check the output of `ls -lR /var/www`? Also, try going to /index.php

Comment: @Ryan how did you solved the Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server problem??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't define ".php" index for Apache

```
<IfModule mime_module>
   AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>
```

see this tutorial [install Apache and php](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

and [install Apache and php](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-fedora-18-lamp)

Comment: I did. Previously i can access the site using ip/html/index.php or ip/html/. After replacing the existing apache html directory, the problem happened. I did that because I want to use ip directly to access the site, without having the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess or httpd.conf file add this line

DirectoryIndex index.php

Answer (score 0):

It has a very simple solution, define directory index in .htaccess file. If no .htaccess file on your website root then add one and put below line into it.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```