# Google Compute Replacing var/www/html Directory

Tags: apache, google-compute-engine

I've launched Wordpress on Google Compute Engine (via their automated launcher process). It installs quickly and easily and visiting the external IP displayed in my Compute Engine VM Instances Dashboard, I am able access the fresh installation of Wordpress.

However, when I `scp` an existing Wordpress installation `oldWPsite` into `var/www/` then replace my `html` directory

```
mv html htmlFRESH 
mv oldWPsite html
```

my site returns a 'failed to open' error. Directory permissions user:group are identical.

Moreso, when I return the directories to their original configuration

```
mv html oldWPsite
mv htmlFRESH html
```

Still, the error persists.

I am familiar with other hosting paradigms where I can easily switch between the publicly served files by simply modifying directory names. Is there something unique about Google Compute Engine? What is the best way to import existing sites, files, etc into the Google Cloud environment?

Replicate

1. Install Wordpress via Google Launcher on a micro-VM.
2. Visit public IP of the VM instance.
3. SCP a fresh installation of Wordpress to`var/www`.
4. Replace the Google installed `html` directory with the newly created and copied Wordpress directory using `mv` commands.
5. Visit public IP of the VM instance.

===
Referenced Questions:

[after replacing /var/www/html directory, apache does not work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466263/after-replacing-var-www-html-directory-apache-does-not-work-anymore)

[permission for var/www/html directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894907/permission-for-var-www-html-directory) - a2enmod command unrecognized on new G-compute VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import .htaccess file had https redirect which caused the server to prompt failure since https is not setup in a fresh launch of Wordpress through GCE. Compounding the issue, the browser cache held that memory when the previous site was moved back to the initial conditions.

Per usual, the solution involved the investigation of user errors.